# SciLab: where do functions live / need to live?

Tags: scripting, scilab

I'm learning SciLab and I need to figure out the equivalent from MATLAB for running user-defined functions.

I'm used to MATLAB, where when you type `foo(27)`, it looks for the `foo.m` script in the current directory and then the MATLAB path, and if it finds one, it calls that function with argument 27.

What's the equivalent to SciLab? It doesn't seem to want to look in the current directory for the appropriate .sci file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scilab, you need to explicitly load the script that contains the function. Assuming you've changed your directory to the directory where the function file is loaded, which can be done in Scilab using the menu buttons or the following command:

```
cd("path/to/working/directory")
```

Now you load the function file. Assuming the function `foo` is stored in a file called `foo.sci`, you need to load this script using the following command:

```
exec("foo.sci")
```

Now you should be able to use your function as you would be able in MATLAB.

```
foo(27)
```

Comment: `exec foo.sci` is a shorthand, as well as `cd path/to/working/directory`